# Resize Image of any size to fixed dimension using C# ASP.Net web form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, image-resizing

I have done image resizing while allowing user to upload a specific size image and then crop them to different dimension i have also used jCrop in project to allow users to upload a image of specific size and then select the image area & crop it accordingly.

In new project i have a requirement where user can upload any size image which is at least larger than 500Px in width and then i have to allow user to select the part of image using jCrop and then save image in different dimension of 475x313 , 310x205 while maintaining the aspect ration.

I can do it with if i allow the used to upload a fixed size image but i am not sure how i can handle variable size image.

I also need to display the image uploaded before cropping in a fixed size box.. let us say 300x200. in this area i have to allow the user to select the part of the image before i can crop.

Issue i am facing is how to handle variable length image and show it is a fixed image box of 300x200px.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on [using jCrop with dynamically-resized uploaded images](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2011/combining-jcrop-and-server-side-image-resizing), which seems to be what you're needing.

If you're looking for an open-source ASP.NET control that does it for you, [check out cropimage.net](http://cropimage.net_).

Answer (score 0):

Want to going to by `programmatically` than you can try this :

if you are using `file upload` for upload images

```
    string path = Path.GetFileName(fileuploaderID.PostedFile.FileName); 
    ConvertThumbnails(width, height, fileuploaderID.FileBytes, path);
```

**your function**

```
       public void ConvertThumbnails(int width, int height, byte[] filestream, string path)
      {
        // create an image object, using the filename we just retrieved

        var stream = new MemoryStream(filestream);
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

         try
              {  
                int fullSizeImgWidth = image.Width;
                int fullSizeImgHeight = image.Height;
                float imgWidth = 0.0F;
                float imgHeight = 0.0F;
                imgWidth = width;
                imgHeight = height;

                Bitmap thumbNailImg = new Bitmap(image, (int)imgWidth, (int)imgHeight);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                // Save to memory using the Jpeg format
                thumbNailImg.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                // read to end
                byte[] bmpBytes = ms.GetBuffer();
                item.Attachments.Add(path, bmpBytes);
                thumbNailImg.Dispose();
                ms.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            image.Dispose();
        }
    }
```